# Calling base class function - class inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

Please check out the following example:

```
MyBaseClass = function(a) {
     this.a = a;
};

$.extend(MyBaseClass.prototype, {
    init: function() {
        console.log('I am initializing the base class');
    }
});

MyChildClass = $.extend(MyBaseClass, {
    init: function() {
        MyBaseClass.prototype.init();
        console.log('I am initializing the child class');
    }
});

var = new MyChildClass();
var.init();
```

Тhis should output both 'I am initializing the base class' and 'I am initializing the child class'.

I need to be able to inherit the class MyBaseClass, but still to be able to call his init() method at the beginning of the new init() method.

How do I do that?

Comment: `$.extend` doesn't do what you think.

Comment: kind of a glaring issue with this code is the use of `var` at the bottom

Comment: What is `$.extend` anyway?

Comment: @FelixKling one is defined by jQuery. I'm assuming this one.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm sure Felix knew it but was pointing that OP should have added the relevant tag.

Comment: @dystroy I'm well aware of that fact :-)

Comment: @Jan: Yeah, everyone is *assuming* jQuery, but it could be anything really ;) There is no hint of jQuery in the OP's code. Anyways... question is resolved.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[jQuery's extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) doesn't build inheritance but *"Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object"*.

Use [prototype based inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) to achieve your inheritance and explicitly call the "super" method :

```
MyBaseClass = function(a) {
     this.a = a;
};
MyBaseClass.prototype.init = function() {
    console.log('I am initializing the base class');
};

MyChildClass = function(a) {
  this.a = a;
}
MyChildClass.prototype = Object.create(MyBaseClass.prototype); // makes MyChildClass "inherit" of MyBaseClass
MyChildClass.prototype.init = function() {
    MyBaseClass.prototype.init.call(this); // calls super init function
    console.log('I am initializing the child class');
};

var child= new MyChildClass();
child.init();
```

[Output](http://jsbin.com/ekuyew/1/edit) :

```
I am initializing the base class
I am initializing the child class
```

Comment: Should `Object.create` be used here?

Comment: As OP speaks of "classes" and inheritance, I personally feel that prototype is more suited.

Comment: Maybe Jan meant to use `MyChildClass.prototype = Object.create(MyBaseClass.prototype);`. That would be a better approach for inheritance IMHO. Instantiating a new instance of the parent *can* have drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QqQe3/)**

Couple of things. `extend` really just adds on properties, it doesn't do much. So you need to have a function for your class ready, inherit from the base class, and then use extend on that classes prototype.

```
function MyChildClass(){};
MyChildClass.prototype = new MyBaseClass();
$.extend(MyChildClass.prototype, {
 init: function() {
    MyBaseClass.prototype.init();
    console.log('I am initializing the child class');
 }
});
```

Here is another approach that I like to use for inheritance - when the specificity of methods is going to be an issue - which is to store the base class in its own property

```
function MyChildClass(){};
MyChildClass.prototype = new MyBaseClass();
MyChildClass.prototype.base = new MyBaseClass();
$.extend(MyChildClass.prototype, {
 init: function() {
    this.base.init();
    console.log('I am initializing the child class');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another prototype based pattern to achieve this goal:

```
MyBaseClass = function(a) {
     this.a = a;
};

MyBaseClass.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        console.log('I am initializing the base class');
    }
};

MyChildClass = function() {};
MyChildClass.prototype = $.extend(new MyBaseClass(), {
    init: function() {
        this.super.init.call(this);
        console.log('init child');
    },
    super: MyBaseClass.prototype,
    constructor: MyChildClass
});

var a = new MyChildClass();
a.init();
```

Output:

```
I am initializing the base class
init child
```

Here `this.super` stores reference to base class.

Comment: Honest question : why are you specifying the constructor ?

Comment: @dystroy - I actually saw that in the jquery source code. I think it is because sometimes the constructor points to the wrong function at times (can't remember the exact scenario to get it to do that at the moment).

Comment: @dystroy To be able to use `instanceof`. `a instanceof MyChildClass`

Comment: There's a problem with your pattern : you lose the context in using `this.super.init()` or `this.super.anyfunc()`. This `super` looks like a bad idea.

Comment: @dystroy You are right, thank you. Well this is just another pattern, why not, some people use it.

Comment: FWIW, `instanceof` does not make use of the `constructor` property. It simply compares every prototype in the prototype chain of the left operand (the object) against the `prototype` property if the right operand (the constructor function). The `constructor` property does not have any significance for the internal workings (but I still think it makes sense to have it referring to the correct function).

Comment: I hesitated to make this comment because I don't want to make it sound as an unfair attack (it's an interesting aditional answer anyway) but I really think this `super` is a bad idea : it steals from the semantic of languages having class inheritance but it doesn't mean the same thing at all as here it doesn't point to the instance and thus can't be used in the same manner. It feels too much like an attempt to make JS looks like a language it isn't.

Comment: @dystroy Yes, I agree. And personally I prefer pure prototypal + copying own properties approach for inheritance. By the way in ECMAScript 6 we will have classes, and `super` reference to parent consrtuctor so it would be look like `super.init()` in our example.

Comment: I'm so looking forward to ES6 :)